How to set a default ringtone for apps (not SIM/phone calls) on android 13 and android 14?
Android 13 and 14, under settings, there's only options for SIM specific ringtones:

There's no "Default" ringtone! (NOTE: screen shot from websearch. I'm using a stock android on a PIXEL, and on a MOTOROLA. Both have the same options as the screen shot, which is for illustration that there is "ring tone" for each SIM card, and no "default")
Yet, every app is set to use "Ringtone: Default"!
This causes apps like whatsapp, to ring for whatsapp calls using the original default of the phone (which is NOT set to either SIM card's ringtones)... now i get the atrociously horrible and unbearable "hello moto" ringtone for those apps.
I could configure every single app to use a different ring tone, but why if they are all using the "default"... the question is how do i set the "default" i want?
I cannot believe google screwed up that bad again and there's no way to set it. I just think this is usual google usability and the setting is hidden in some completely non-obvious place.
--
Another tidbit. I have four phones.
Pixel pro with one SIM card and one E-Sim. (both being used)
Pixel with one SIM card and one E-sim (only physical sim present, esim empty)
Motorola with one SIM card and one E-sim (only physical sim present, esim empty)
Motorola with two physical sim cards, but only one inserted.

On all phones, they run android 13 and 14, stock from manufacturer. And the ringtone settings are exactly the same as the included screenshot (but with the regular Material design styling)

The screenshots don't look like they were taken on a plain AOSP/Pixel phone - they look modified by the manufacturer. On which phone model have you made that screenshots?

@Robert pls ignore the screen shot style. I got it from a web search. It looks different but show the same options on my plain android devices (Motorola, Pixel). (screenshot looks like a samsung btw. but again, ignore the color/icons)
